# Trigger Local notification to the killed/Quitted App on iBeacon Detection

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I have triggered a Local Notification whenever the application comes into the region of iBeacon. I used `CLLocationManager` to continuously Monitor the Location changes.

The app is working fine both in Foreground and Background Modes, which triggers the Local Notification whenever the device enters the iBeacon Region.

I want to trigger a Local Notification, when the device enters the iBeacon Region, even **If the App is not launched once (or) If the App is Quitted/Terminated/Killed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No special programming is needed to make this work.**  If you can make your app do this in the background, it should also work after the app is killed or on reboot (if enough time is allowed to pass for CoreLocation to initialize.)

If you are not seeing this work, you may be experiencing a test setup issue:

- Make sure you have exited the beacon region before killing the app or rebooting.
- Make sure you wait long enough.  In some cases detections can take up to 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, David. Thanks for the reply, There isn't any location notification triggering when I quit the App, even though I wrote code to show a Local Notification in "didEnterRegion" delegate. But the App Icon is been shown at the lock Screen when the device enters the iBeacon Region. Would you be able to schedule/Trigger local Notification?

Comment: Please post the code in your app delegate.  Cannot think of why my it would not work if it works in the background

Comment: Thanks David, the notifications are working in Foreground, Background or even when the App is killed/Teminated, when the source code are moved to AppDelegate Class.